# ASP Classic - determining if a file is binary or text (ascii) using FileSystemObject

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, filesystemobject

If I categorize files as binary (eg: .exe, .mp3, .docx, .pdf) and text (eg: rtf, txt, html, xml), then how can we use the classic ASP's FSO to determine what kind of file a particular file is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked it up at the Internet all users are the same opinion. There is no direct way to make a difference.
Apparently you have to do it manually. This [link](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=91871) gives you a set of rules to make a difference between a text and a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/04/20/410127.aspx), the FSO isn't meant for binary files. But using .Read(n) to get the first few characters and compare them to known signatures should work.

P.S.

If you do a full scan to classify the data, as reporter porposed, make sure you use more modern rules (e.g. a UTF16 text file could contain 50% 'zeros').